# How do I roll back to a previous installation of WINE without knowing what that version was?

Tags: software-installation, wine, games

I've searched for a similar question and haven't found one yet, so here goes:

How do I roll back to a previous installation of WINE without knowing what that version was?

Backstory:

I played a game on my Ubuntu machine using WINE a few months ago and noticed that an error kept occurring under certain circumstances that made it almost unplayable.I stopped playing.

Fast forward a few months and a few WINE updates and I decide to give the game another go. To my delight, the error has stopped occurring. Then, I notice a new WINE update and decide to install it.

Using these commands:

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Now the game is performing the same error and it has become unplayable again.

So, my question is:

Without knowing what that last version of WINE was, how do I get back to it? This game is in early alpha and has not been released yet. It's also a very 'niche' sort of game, so there wont be a large amount of people playing it, and even fewer on Linux (I'm the only one I know of). I can't expect any help from other players. They're all on either Windows or Mac.

Comment: How to do it without knowing which version it was? Well, start by finding out which version it was.

Comment: Thank you! I wouldn't have known to look for that!
I was so ready to be mad at you for what looked like such a cheeky answer, but then using the link you provided, I found out that I was using the discontinued Staging Branch of Wine before. So, I've switched back to that now, and everything's working great!

Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

If your Wine version has been upgraded, you may find packages version detail (upgrade from which version and to which version) inside `/var/log/dpkg.log`

Depending on when you did the upgrade, look at `/var/log/dpkg.log.1` or other gziped `/var/log/dpkg.log.X.gz` (where X is a number)

For recent logs, you can for example type something like :

```
grep wine /var/log/dpkg.log* | grep upgrade | less
```

For older ones you might try :

```
zgrep wine /var/log/dpkg.log* | grep upgrade | less
```

Here is the output i am getting for my computer :

```
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2017-08-28 11:29:02 upgrade wine1.6-i386:i386 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2017-08-28 11:29:03 upgrade wine1.6:amd64 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2017-08-28 11:29:04 upgrade wine1.6-amd64:amd64 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2017-08-28 11:29:45 upgrade wine:amd64 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2
```

Then, at the end of each line, you can see something like this :

```
wine1.6-i386:i386 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2
```

In this example, the upgrade was made from version 1.6.2-0ubuntu**14** to version 1.6.2-0ubuntu14.**2**

Comment: Thank you! The log on my computer showed the changes separated by day for the past month. It was very helpful.